# Move Dynamic Html with jQuery ( Append/Copy )

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to move an Html content generated dynamically in php inside an outer div:

Ex.

```
<div class="top-category>
    <div class="cat-container">Category</div>
        <div class="categoryA">CatA</div>
        <div class="categoryB">CatA</div>
        <div class="categoryC">CatA</div>
        <div class="categoryD">CatA</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to move all, inside another div under:

```
<div class="bottom-container">HERE ALL CONTENT</div>
```

How i can do via jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".top-category" ).appendTo( ".bottom-container " );
});

</scrript>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$.detach()` to remove required DOM element from body and then append to destination DOM element as follows:

```
$("div.bottom-container").append($("div.top-category" ).detach());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.top-category').clone().appendTo('.bottom-container');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-category">
    <div class="cat-container">Category</div>
        <div class="categoryA">CatA</div>
        <div class="categoryB">CatA</div>
        <div class="categoryC">CatA</div>
        <div class="categoryD">CatA</div>
    </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="bottom-container">HERE ALL CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to move content of "top-category" in to "bottom-container"

Here is jquery code for it

```
$(function(){
    var $child = $(".top-category > div").detach();
    $(".bottom-container").append($child);
})
```

Here is working JSFiddle [code](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/frpbLz3f/)